# pandas take average on odd rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to fill in data between each row in a dataframe with an average of current and next row (where columns are numeric)

starting data:

```
   time value value_1  value-2
0   0    0      4        3
1   2    1      6        6
```

intermediate df:

```
   time value value_1  value-2
0   0    0      4        3
1   1    0      4        3     #duplicate of row 0
2   2    1      6        6
3   3    1      6        6     #duplicate of row 2
```

I would like to create df_1:

```
   time value value_1  value-2
0   0    0      4        3
1   1    0.5    5        4.5     #average of row 0 and 2
2   2    1      6        6
3   3    2      8        8       #average of row 2 and 4
```

To to this I appended a copy of the starting dataframe to create the intermediate dataframe shown above:

```
df = df_0.append(df_0)
df.sort_values(['time'], ascending=[True], inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index()
df['value_shift'] = df['value'].shift(-1)
df['value_shift_1'] = df['value_1'].shift(-1)
df['value_shift_2'] = df['value_2'].shift(-1)
```

then I was thinking of applying a function to each column:

```
def average_vals(numeric_val):
    #average every odd row
    if int(row.name) % 2 != 0:
        #take average of value and value_shift for each value
        #but this way I need to create 3 separate functions
```

Is there a way to do this without writing a separate function for each column and applying to each column one by one (in real data I have tens of columns)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this method using [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`DataFrame.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html)

```
df.reindex(np.arange(len(df.index) * 2) / 2).interpolate().reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### Explanation

Reindex, in half steps `reindex(np.arange(len(df.index) * 2) / 2)`

This gives a DataFrame like this:

```
     time  value  value_1  value-2
0.0   0.0    0.0      4.0      3.0
0.5   NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
1.0   2.0    1.0      6.0      6.0
1.5   NaN    NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Then use `DataFrame.interpolate` to fill in the `NaN` values .... the default will be linear interpolation, so mean in this case.

Finaly, use `.reset_index(drop=True)` to fix your index.

Should give

```
   time  value  value_1  value-2
0   0.0    0.0      4.0      3.0
1   1.0    0.5      5.0      4.5
2   2.0    1.0      6.0      6.0
3   2.0    1.0      6.0      6.0
```